# Why does a 74LS189 RAM chip light-up an LED connected to its re-inverted output when data word is HIGH while a 7489 RAM chip cannot?

Tags: ttl, ram

I have thought on it a lot and summarizing my confusion here. I have two SN7489N chips whose Ioh is 20uA (not sufficient to light-up an LED). Correct me if I'm wrong that Ioh is the maximum current it will draw when output is high (i.e. when memory word is a low bit in case of 7489)? On the other hand, Iol is 12mA (i.e. when memory word is a HIGH bit)?

So, when I attach a hex inverter to the outputs of the 7489, which has its own Ioh and Iol readings in its datasheet, what will be my final Ioh and Iol?

Also, how can a 74LS189 chip light-up an LED connected to its re-inverted output (using hex inverter) when data word is a HIGH bit while a 7489 cannot even when datasheets of both show similar readings for Iol (i.e. 16mA)? [Source: https://youtu.be/uYXwCBo40iA?t=610 for 74LS189]

Comment: What LED? Use red or Yellow.

Comment: A 7-segment display common anode LED (red), like this one: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41Araxi2mwL._SX342_.jpg

Comment: CA uses Vol to drive segment with A on 5V . No problem Vol  but must use series Rs. If LED Vf=2V and Vol=0,5V then Anode must be 2.5V or add Rs to each cathode so cathode = 2.8V@6mA...e.g. 470 ohms approx

Comment: Remember TTL is asymmetric on Iol,Ioh and Iil,Iih

Comment: Can you please suggest me a way to be able to light-up an LED (not necessarily 7-segment display led) whose positive end is connected to the re-inverted output of 7489 when memory data (D1) is a HIGH bit?

I have seen this video https://youtu.be/uYXwCBo40iA?t=610 where he is able to light-up the LED when data word is a high bit and Vol and Iol are similar for both 7489 and 74189.

Comment: So if you drive low, Rs is necessary, but not for drive high with common cathode in TTl only

Comment: So is memory=1, invert=0, LED = on ?? It is better with no inverter and drive Voh ON with CC LED  but since you have CA , then you need Rs

Comment: When memory =1, invert = 0, LED lights-up only when the inverted output is connected at its negative end and positive end is connected to 5v. I am trying to light-up the LED by connecting its positive end to re-inverted output .

Comment: In other words, 74LS189 can light-up an LED connected at its positive end to the re-inverted output but 7489 does not do that. Why?

Comment: If you tell me voltage across LED, then I can answer

Comment: Do you have LS89 with open collector?

Comment: Yes. And I have tried using a pull-up resistor too, 220 Ohms.

Comment: Multimeter reading for a HIGH output reads 0.25v and 0.1v for a LOW output when voltage across IC is 4.79volts.

Comment: 0.25 is not high try R pull-up ,no LED

Comment: I just used a 220 ohm resistor but the reading I am getting is 0.25v. I think I know nothing and should giveup now.

Comment: Check your wiring for write clock and data input or else you have a short? Check Vcc, Vee on each pin, then verify each input, then output no load.  and 20uA is Iih not Ioh

Comment: I dont think I understand the concept of input current. I always look at Ioh and Iol because I think that it is the output current during high and low output states respectively and should determine if it will light-up an LED or not (making sure that output pin is connected at right side of led as per the output state low or high).

My experiment was simple. I was trying to light-up an LED using 7489 just like it lights-up in case of 74189 in Ben Eater's video (https://youtu.be/uYXwCBo40iA?t=610). But I tried everything to fail.

Comment: I even realized just now that a standalone hex inverter lights-up an LED only in low output state, not in high output state. However, I had a belief that an LED can be lit in both low and high output state of inverter, just by making sure it is forward biased. This gives me an idea why inverter wont light-up an LED when connected to outputs of 7489 when memory is 1, because it will receive 0 input and will go in HIGH output state, hence no light in LED

Comment: Yes high side is weak in TTL since input Iih=20uA and there is no need

Comment: Beware of fake 74LS189 RAM chips sold from china.